# Setting a Sitecore Item Url by C# to a third party server

Tags: c#, sitecore

In a specific kind of situation, I had to obtain certain data through a RESTful request from a cloud server and then process and present them along the normal Sitecore items. I converted the data from a RESTful request to Sitecore Item through the following code:

```
 private static Item Itemize(HubSpotResult hubSpotResult)
        {

            Database webDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");

            TemplateItem template = webDb.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/User Defined/Pages/HubSpotBlogs");
            var id = ID.NewID;
            var templateId = template.ID;
            var titleFieldId = ID.NewID;
            var dateFieldId = ID.NewID;
            var navigationTitleFieldId = ID.NewID;
            var def = new ItemDefinition(id,"HubSpotBlog", templateId, ID.Null);

            var fields = new FieldList();
            fields.Add(titleFieldId, "Title");
            fields.Add(dateFieldId, "Date");
            fields.Add(navigationTitleFieldId, "NavigationTitle");
            var data = new ItemData(def, Language.Parse("en"),new Sitecore.Data.Version(1), fields);
            var dateTime = GetPublicationDate(hubSpotResult.publish_date).ToString();
            var sitecoreStyleDateTime = DateUtil.ParseDateTime(dateTime,DateTime.Now);
            Item item;
            using (new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                item = new Item(id, data, webDb);
                item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                item.Fields["Date"].Value =DateUtil.ToIsoDate(sitecoreStyleDateTime.Date);
                item.Fields["Title"].Value = hubSpotResult.html_title;
                item.Fields["NavigationTitle"].Value = hubSpotResult.html_title;
                Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField link = item.Fields["NavigationTitle"];

                link.Url = hubSpotResult.url;
                link.Text = hubSpotResult.html_title;
                item.Editing.EndEdit();
            }


            return item;
        }
```

Currently, I can't get the Url to the items that are created in this way as the the items don't exist on the Sitecore tree, however to render the link I need to set the Url of the item to point to the cloud server.
Is there a good way to Set the Url, so LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item) can get the url to the cloud server and also renders the title of the link or item?

Comment: You are doing some pretty weird stuff here..  if I understand your goal correctly, I think you should be looking into a (read-only) custom data provider and maybe a custom linkprovider to go along.. (the linkprovider is the way to customize the GetItemUrl function)

Comment: @Gatogordo yes, it is a weird situation that has landed on my desk.

Comment: Why do you have to create a "virtual" item to present the data here? Why not just wildcard the Url and then get the data from the REST service and present it. Seems overkill to create the Item.

Comment: @RichardSeal part of the data come from Sitecore and part from a third party service like Hubspot. But ultimately they are all presented under the same list in the view. I have inherited this code from another developer with new requirements and hence this weird situation.

Comment: ah ok - normally for situations like this, I would create a view model that contained the item data and also the custom data. You will add extra overhead by creating the virtual item. The performance will not be as good. But if you are stuck with that see my answer below.

Comment: @RichardSeal I have to mention that the source code is based on ASP.Net Webforms and not MVC. That is another restriction that I am dealing with. Otherwise it would be quite easy to work this out with ViewModel and razor syntax in the view.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this would be to override the `LinkProvider` with a custom one. When it see's an item based on the template you are using to create the "virtual" items, you can then use the data on that item to workout what the link to create should be. If the item is not of that template, then you can just pass it through to the base `LinkProvider`

```cs
public class MyLinkProvider : Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider
{
    public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
    {

        var templateID = new ID("<your template Id >");

        if (item == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(options, "options");

        if (item.TemplateID == templateID) 
        {
            // Build your custom url here
            return "custom url";
        }
        else 
        {
            return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
        }
    }
}
```

Then patch that in via an include file:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <linkManager>
            <providers>
                <add name="sitecore">
                    <patch:attribute name="type">MyApplication.MyLinkProvider, MyApplication</patch:attribute>
                </add>
            </providers>
        </linkManager>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This will let normal items generate in the standard Sitecore way, and you can choose how the items link should be built.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem in quite an easier way. 
I added a new field called Url with type of General Link to the template that I had created in Sitecore for these temporary virtual items. 
I used it in my virtual item creation like this:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField link = item.Fields["Url"];
link.Url = hubSpotResult.url;
link.Text = hubSpotResult.html_title;
```

then, I grabbed the Url that I wanted in the same GetUrl extension like this:

```
 if (i != null && i.Name == "HubSpotBlog")
            {
                LinkField link = i.Fields["Url"];
                strUrl = link.Url;
            }
```

the repeated took care of the rest of it and I was able to render values that I wanted on the view.